# Electric flux due to a charge on a square surface

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]

what is the flux through the square if a charge q is placed on the surface of the square ?

Now,

according to me if we use the solid angle method
the flux should be
$$([q/\epsilon]*2\pi)/4\pi$$

as the solid angle is $2\pi$
however I'm not sure if this is correct :(

.

Now,what if I placed the charge over some distance d above the square can i still use solid angles?

I feel it's not possible to use solid angles in the second case.

(To sum it up can I always use solid angles to find flux??)

(Edit: I am a high school student so complex math stuff isn't good with me :(.Also, I'm not too good with solid angles )

[image]

also I feel that the flux cant be zero as it can be clearly  seen that some field lines are passing along the area vector through the y -axis

Comment: Your image doesn't line up with the text. The charge is in the middle of the square in the image.

Comment: In your drawing, you are misinterpreting the effects of perspective for the electric field pointing outside of the xz-plane. All the red arrows are actually parallel to the xz-plane and they only look like they were pointing outside, due to perspective.

Answer (score 4):

If the charge is in the surface, the electric field vectors are also parallel to the surface, due to symmetry. Then

$$\Phi_E=\int \vec E\cdot d\vec A=\int \vec E\cdot \vec n d A=0$$

because of $\vec E\cdot \vec n=0$. No need for solid angles to get that result.

The electric field of a point charge at the origin is (in suitable charge units)

$$\vec E = q \frac{\vec r}{r^3}$$

For every plane through the point charge, the electric field in that plane is trivially parallel to that plane (because $\vec E\sim \vec r$). Hence, it is perpendicular to the normal of that plane.

Comment: i dont think this answers my question :(

Comment: You told that you're not sure if your result is correct. It is not, as shown above.

Comment: i think u r wrong

Comment: u are ignoring the fact that electric field can actually pass through the surface as well

Comment: i think the field isn't perpendicular

Comment: Okay, maybe you could sketch your line of thinking.

Comment: ok sorry for being rude, but i don't think ur right

Comment: "i think the field isn't perpendicular" It is, at least if the charge is in the plane. Again, due to symmetry.

Comment: @oliver is right, assuming we understand the question properly. Another way to see this that doesn't require any calculations is by symmetry. Note that flux has a sign, it can be positive or negative. By symmetry (try drawing a picture) two equal charges that lie the same distance above and below the square have equal and opposite fluxes. Thus, since a charge on the square is the same distance above the square (zero) as below the square, its flux must be equal to its own opposite. Therefore its flux is zero.

Comment: If you don't clarify why you think like you think, I can't help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: im sorry , i shall improvise right now

Comment: @oliver i have added my thoughts

Comment: @MeetLalwani even though it is true that there are lines going through the surface, they are parallel to it, hence parallel to dA and therefore giving a dot product equal to zero

Comment: @MeetLalwani if you want a more intuitive explanation, here is my best shot: flux emerges whenever E is going through a surface. Think of shooting small bullets to a sheet of paper. If they go through then there is some bullet "flux". If you were to fire them completely from the side, they wouldnt actually be penetrating the surface. This case is similar: the E field is just "barely touching" the surface. Thus none of it is penetrating through, and the flux is zero. Hope it helps